# Getting Excel to recognize different series from a table correctly for a scatter graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have data in a table as follows..

sample of the table with data:

[image]

So in the table:

- Item 1 sold twice 39 days since it was uploaded.
- Item 2 has sold once 56 days from being uploaded.
- Item 5 has sold 16 times on different days since being uploaded.

All I want is to be able to select all of the data (there are 400 rows) and for excel to group together each unique "item ID" as one series (x axis) & then plot the days it sold ( Y axis).

I really do not want to have to do this manually as I will be adding data eventually.

I would like the graph to look like this but obviously with a lot more series.

Example of what I would like the graph to look like:

[image]

Comment: So the problem is that scatter produces one color and one legend item? You want to display different colors and different legend items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, and while data may look ugly, is pretty quick to put together.

First, add as many columns as needed to match the number of distinct items you have. The column headers should match your item names.

Then, here's a formula for cell C2:

```
    =IF($A2=C$1,$B2,NA())
```

Drag the formula across and down.

Lastly, create your scatter using column A (Item) and columns C through J (your new columns).

Final results:

[image]

Comment: I dont know where you live or who you are but you Sir or Madam are a life saver!

Thank you so so much :D

Comment: No problem. Please consider marking as an approved answer, thanks.